# Php artisan not working (laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

Suddenly when i type `php artisan` or any artisan command 
i seen this message

> [ErrorException]
>     Trying to get property of non-object

I tried the following

1- `php artisan clear-compiled`

2- To delete `vendor` directory and use `composer install` Or `composer update`

3- clone a standard Laravel app  and put my files `app` dir and my config
 and use `composer` commands but with step the error has changed to be

> [ErrorException]
>     Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event    returned with an error
>
> [RuntimeException]
>     Error Output:

Any Suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: So you can't run php artisan in cmd?
Have you checked your PATH?

Comment: did you add custom [artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan) or install new vendor package recently?

Comment: Can you try to delete the bootstrap/cache/compiled.php and run composer install again?

Comment: It's possible that one of your service providers is causing the problem. I'd look at the files inside your `app/Providers` directory. By default, they're fairly empty so check to see if you added any lines of code that might be causing the error.

Comment: @ThomasKim :you are right i found it finally

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you have this issue when you use your app files. It probably means that you have some problem in constructor - you try to run function and the object is not initialized. You should not set up things in constructors (look for example at your controllers) or you will get some "strange" errors and your artisan won't work

Answer (score 1):

After navigation on my app i found  the issue in my `ServiceProviderClass` `boot()` method in particular when comment one method get data according to subDomain name `artisan` worked well

Laravel Doc hint for this method

**This method is called after all other service providers have been registered, meaning you have access to all other services that have been registered by the framework**

for more read [Laravel service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers)